# React Navigation for multiple pages

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm new to React Native. Currently I'm working on an e-commerce app and want to implement navigation. Here's my question: what's the most efficient way to do that.
My project has multiple pages (more than 20) and I'm also using Bottom bar navigation.

I've checked the [official documentation of React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/) and checked lots of examples online.